# Dwarf Fortress Legendary Dining Hall

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What makes a room a "legendary dining hall"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A legendary dining room is a [dining room](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Dining_room) with very high [room](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Room#Quality) value.

Room value is determined by the quality of the floors and walls of the room, and any items in it.  You can increase a room's value by [smoothing](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Smoothing) and [engraving](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Engraving) it.  Engravings have quality of their own, so it's best to use a highly skilled [engraver](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Engraver) to do that work.  Adding [high value items](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Item_quality) such as statues also  helps raise the value.  Also keep in mind the size of the room and the material the room is dug out of has an effect; who wouldn't want to live in a grand room made out of *Gold*?

Comment: Size also matters, I believe. I'm always surprised at how little effort it takes to make a dining hall legendary.

Comment: @Javadoc, thanks, I touched that up.  I'm always surprised to find it too.  I often do it without trying.

Comment: The quality of a room is calculated by the value of each floor and wall tile plus the value of each decoration in it. Start with 20x20 and even an unimproved room will be considered pretty nice.