# How to make a meager/decent/great dining room or bedroom?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dwarf Fortress Legendary Dining Hall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/dwarf-fortress-legendary-dining-hall)

What are the minimum requirements for different levels of dining rooms or bedrooms? How can you make a room to specific quality level?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/dwarf-fortress-legendary-dining-hall

Answer (score 2):

General things that make a room better are the size of the room, smoothness/engravedness of the walls and floor and the quality of the objects in the room.

I know that a 3x3 bedroom with nothing but a bed in will be a meagre bedroom, even if the walls are smooth.

The quality depends on so many factors, I wouldn't be surprised if there did not exist a hard and fast rule for getting rooms of a specific quality...

Comment: If I make a gigantic room with loads and loads of low quality items, will that be considered high level room?

Comment: I have no idea. Why don't you try it? I have a 8x8 or 10x10 dining room that's all engraved. It has a bunch of low quality tables and chairs in, and it is legendary. [I'm guessing they're low quality, they were pretty much the first things my craftsdorf made...)